# passport local not working for multiple model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local, passport-jwt

I have used passport local for authenticate purpose but not working.It is working only one from these two(user and admin).I do not know why it is working like this.If anyone know please help to find solution.

passportconfig.js:

```
 const passportuser = require('passport');
 const localStrategyuser = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 const mongooseuser = require('mongoose'); 

 const passportAdmin = require('passport');
 const localStrategyAdmin = require('passport-local').Strategy; 
 const mongooseadmin = require('mongoose');

 var User = mongooseuser.model('User'); 
 var Admin = mongooseadmin .model('Admin'); 

 passportuser.use(
 new localStrategyuser({ usernameField: 'email' },
    (username, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ email: username },
            (err, user) => {
                if (err) { return done(err); } else if (!user) {

                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered for User' });
                } else if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password.' });
                } else {
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            });
    })
    );



passportAdmin.use(
new localStrategyAdmin({ usernameField: 'email' },
    (username, password, done) => {
        Admin.findOne({ email: username },
            (err, admin) => {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                // unknown user
                else if (!admin)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Email is not registered for Admin' });
                // wrong password
                else if (!admin.verifyPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password.' });
                // authentication succeeded
                else
                    return done(null, admin);
            });
    })
    );
```

Comment: your code shows that it would authenticate only users from two tables `user` and `admin` so wat u trying to explain is not clear..

Comment: Also `passportuser` and `passportadmin` are same only as you require the same `passport`. So one basically u have one passport and two localstratiges for the same one. SO combining these logics woulud be good. `Requiring` passport or mangoose into two diff variables does not make them different. They are same instance stored in diff variables.

Comment: I got this code from this: https://github.com/CodAffection/MEAN-Stack-Login-and-Logout-in-Angular-6-Part-2

Comment: I am using this for user and admin section..So i do not know how to use it/

Comment: I do not know how to use this for user section and admin section

Comment: How to separate these for user and admin?

Comment: this is quite complex to explain in comments. It depends on ur logic. The question itself is not clear, hence there are not any one trying to help. Please make the question and details clear for people to understand the issue

Comment: Simple:How to use multiple possport local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Panther [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358289/passport-local-not-working-for-multiple-model#comment110287707_62358289) in the comment, `passportuser` and `passportAdmin` is just the same module, you have to create separate `Passport` instances instead of using the default one

```
const { Passport } = require('passport');

const passportuser = new Passport();
const passportAdmin = new Passport();
```

And also as @Panther mentioned, there is no need to `require('mongoose')` multiple times. This would work equally well:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User'); 
const Admin = mongoose.model('Admin');
```

Comment: Working perfectly..Thank you so much :)

Comment: Are you know typescript?